# Письма на Yahoo попадаю в спам, как исправить?

Tags: email, dkim, yahoo

Столкнулся с проблемой, что письма с моего проекта высылаемые на почтовые ящики yahoo.com попадают в папку со спамом. Как исправить ситуацию, чтобы нормально доставлялось?

Заголовки писем:

```
Received-SPF: pass (domain of ***.*** designates 95.XXX.XXX.XXX as permitted sender)
Authentication-Results: mta4343.mail.gq1.yahoo.com  from=***.***; domainkeys=neutral (no sig);  from=***.***; dkim=pass (ok)
```

Смущает, что `domainkeys=neutral`, хотя проверку на DKIM проходит успешно. На все русскоязычные почтовые сервисы (Yandex, Mail.ru, Rambler) и Gmail письма доставляются нормально.

Comment: Я бы написал сразу в суппорт yahoo.com

Comment: @Insider да, уже сделал. смущает то, что они помимо dkim выделяют еще и отдельные domainkeys. что это такое, разве не dkim? у них даже при добавление нового sender'а есть пункт, где надо выбрать что используешь (dkim, domainkeys или оба).

Comment: domainkeys == dkim вообще-то.. не знаю что за фигню они наделали

Comment: @Insider вот и я про то, может они имеют в виду более раннюю версию DKIM, которая сейчас уже не используется?

Comment: на 100% не скажу. попробуйте поменять метод header с simpled на relaxed